# Modern OpenGL with SDL / loading library

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew, glfw

Is it possible to learn ''modern'' OpenGL with SDL2.0, without using a loading wrapper?

I've read that I had to use an OpenGL loading library in order to use a function like glGenVertexArrays.

But if that is the case, which loading library should I use? GLEW doesn't seem to be maintained.
GLFW seems to be new, but if I use that, SDL is not needed any more right?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what a "loading library" is... but I can tell you that while glfw and SDL serve (roughly) the same purpose, GLEW is completely unrelated to either of those two libraries. And GLEW is very much maintained, it is in a state that it really only needs to be updated about once a year when the OpenGL ARB releases a new version of the OpenGL specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GLEW](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew) (which very much is maintained) and GLFW serve very different purposes.  GLEW is an extension wrangler which allows you to access non-standard functionality, and in some cases, standard functionality which isn't exposed by the default development environment.  The most common example of the latter is developing on Windows, where the standard OpenGL header hasn't been updated for any functionality subsequent to OpenGL 1.x.

GLFW on the other hand is an abstraction which is designed to allow you to create windows and OpenGL contexts on a variety of supported platforms without having to write code specific to that platform.  The process of setting up a window on OSX is very different from that of setting up one on Microsoft Windows, and this is what GLFW shields you from.  In this regard GLFW is a subset of the functionality of SDL, which attempts to do the same thing, but with a larger focus, allowing access to audio output and and game device inputs as well.

Whether or not you have to use a loading library such as GLEW with either SDL or GLFW is mostly dictated by the platform you're trying to target and the OpenGL functionality you want to use.  If you're attempting to use modern OpenGL, i.e. 3.x or 4.x, and you're working with a platform that doesn't have full support for it in it's OpenGL headers, then you're probably going to have to rely on GLEW to fill in that gap for you.